# VBA - Fast way to search for keywords

Tags: vba, excel, search

I am performing a keyword search (looping through an Excel column, looking for keywords contained in another spreadsheet, and assigning values to another column in the first spreadsheet if they are found). I'm doing this by making use of for loops and if - else statements, and it's proving to be **rather slow**. The keywords sheet has three columns in which you can enter keywords, and one column used to assign a value. The idea is that the text being scanned should contain all keywords entered in these keyword columns if the value is to be assigned. Placing a "-" before the keyword means that the value should only be assigned if the scanned text does not contain the keyword indicated. See the code below for the method used. The focus of my question in the efficiency of it.

```
    Dim intLoopKeywordsRows As Integer
    Dim intLoopDataShortTextRows As Integer
    Dim strDataShortText As String
    Dim strKeyword_A As String
    Dim strKeyword_B As String
    Dim strKeyword_C As String
    Dim strCheck_B As String
    Dim strCheck_C As String
    Dim lastRow
    Dim i As Integer

    lastRow = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For intLoopKeywordsRows = 2 To lastRow
        For intLoopDataShortTextRows = 2 To lastRow
            '==================================================================================
            '==================================================================================
            If Data.Range("S" & intLoopDataShortTextRows) = "" Then  '===========only if column S is blank
                strDataShortText = Trim(UCase(Data.Range("G" & intLoopDataShortTextRows)))

                strKeyword_A = UCase(wsKeywords.Range("A" & intLoopKeywordsRows))

                strCheck_B = ""
                If Left(wsKeywords.Range("B" & intLoopKeywordsRows), 1) = "-" Then
                    strCheck_B = "Neg"
                    strKeyword_B = UCase(Right(wsKeywords.Range("B" & intLoopKeywordsRows), Len(wsKeywords.Range("B" & intLoopKeywordsRows)) - 1))
                ElseIf wsKeywords.Range("B" & intLoopKeywordsRows) <> "" Then
                    strCheck_B = "Pos"
                    strKeyword_B = UCase(wsKeywords.Range("B" & intLoopKeywordsRows))
                End If

                strCheck_C = ""
                If Left(wsKeywords.Range("C" & intLoopKeywordsRows), 1) = "-" Then
                    strCheck_C = "Neg"
                    strKeyword_C = UCase(Right(wsKeywords.Range("C" & intLoopKeywordsRows), Len(wsKeywords.Range("C" & intLoopKeywordsRows)) - 1))
                ElseIf wsKeywords.Range("C" & intLoopKeywordsRows) <> "" Then
                    strCheck_C = "Pos"
                    strKeyword_C = UCase(wsKeywords.Range("C" & intLoopKeywordsRows))
                End If

                Dim Check_JumpLoop As Integer
                Check_JumpLoop = 0
                '================if negative values found then go to next Data Text======================
                If (strCheck_B = "Neg" And InStr(strDataShortText, strKeyword_B) > 0) Or (strCheck_C = "Neg" And InStr(strDataShortText, strKeyword_C) > 0) Then
                    Check_JumpLoop = 1
                End If
                '########################################################################################

                '========================================================================================
                If Check_JumpLoop = 0 Then
                    If strCheck_B = "Pos" And strCheck_C = "Pos" Then
                        If InStr(strDataShortText, strKeyword_A) > 0 And InStr(strDataShortText, strKeyword_B) > 0 And InStr(strDataShortText, strKeyword_C) > 0 Then
                            Data.Range("S" & intLoopDataShortTextRows) = wsKeywords.Range("E" & intLoopKeywordsRows)
                        End If
                    ElseIf strCheck_B = "Pos" And strCheck_C <> "Pos" Then
                        If InStr(strDataShortText, strKeyword_A) > 0 And InStr(strDataShortText, strKeyword_B) > 0 Then
                            Data.Range("S" & intLoopDataShortTextRows) = wsKeywords.Range("E" & intLoopKeywordsRows)
                        End If
                    ElseIf strCheck_B <> "Pos" And strCheck_C = "Pos" Then
                        If InStr(strDataShortText, strKeyword_A) > 0 And InStr(strDataShortText, strKeyword_C) > 0 Then
                            Data.Range("S" & intLoopDataShortTextRows) = wsKeywords.Range("E" & intLoopKeywordsRows)
                        End If
                    ElseIf strCheck_B <> "Pos" And strCheck_C <> "Pos" Then
                        If InStr(strDataShortText, strKeyword_A) > 0 Then
                            Data.Range("S" & intLoopDataShortTextRows) = wsKeywords.Range("E" & intLoopKeywordsRows)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                '########################################################################################
            End If
            '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
            '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
        Next intLoopDataShortTextRows
    Next intLoopKeywordsRows
```

My question is whether there is a faster / more efficient way of doing this?

**EDIT: DATA DESCRIPTION**

The data column contains descriptions, such as "Green Garden Hose".

The Keywords sheet contains three columns for entering keywords. These are singular words such as "HOSE", "GREEN", and "GARDEN". To match a keyword to a Value (which in this case is numeric), it must match all keywords in the three columns, but the columns do not need to be filled. If there is only 1 keyword, only that keyword will be looked for. If there is two keywords in two of the columns, the description must contain both etc.

Placing a "-" before a keyword means that the keyword must now be excluded for the value to be assigned. E.G. say the description is "Blue Panel", and the first two keyword columns contains "PANEL" and "-BLUE", the value would not be assigned as BLUE must be excluded from the description.

Comment: Arrays are surely much faster: you could load data in arrays and then loop through them. But would you add some more details about how your data (data column, keywords columns) look like?

Comment: Beyond some minor adjustments (better organized If's, using Booleans instead of Strings), what I see as a major trouble is why you have two loops going from 2 to lastRow. Aren't the keywords and the cells you search for on different sheets? In this case the lastRow may be different. Can you also check what the actual value of lastRow is?

Comment: Could you use the `.Find` Method of the range being the column?

Comment: @z32a7ul: Thanks, you are right, I needed two lastRow variables for the two different sheets. That's already really helped the performance, but I'm still interested in a method that would really speed up the performance of this search.

Comment: I recommend what user3598756 told already, use arrays: Dim a as Variant(): Redim a(2 To lastRow): a=Data.Cells(2,7).Resize(2,lastRow) and search in a(i) instead of in the Cells because this way you communicate with Excel only once (a quite expensive action), unlike when you access Cells individually.